# The sequence $\left\{ \frac{5}{n} \right\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is not monotonic, or not convergent, or bounded. Why?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, definition

I recently watched a video where a Calculus instructor asked the viewers to try to come up with a monotonic, unbounded, convergent sequence, if they could, as an exercise to understand these concepts better.

I came up with $$\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty = \left\{ \frac{5}{n} \right\}_{n=1}^\infty$$

1. I claim it is monotonic because because the sequence is decreasing.
2. I claim it is convergent because as $n \to \infty, \, a_n \to 0$.
3. I claim it is unbounded because for every one of its members, we can always find a smaller one.

However, right after the exercise, we were presented with the following theorem:

> If a sequence is convergent, then it is bounded.

Hence my solution must be wrong, and at least one of my claims must be false. But I'm not sure which one, or why. Is anyone able to shed some light on this?

Comment: But it's actually bounded by $0$ from below. Bound does not to have be an element of sequence, it can be even $-10000$ in this case

Comment: Do the braces represent fractional part, or just a sequence of numbers?  If you just mean a sequence, the more usual way would be $a_n=\frac 5n$

Comment: @RossMillikan Just a sequence of numbers, I don't know what "fractional part" means. Sorry if it's confusing, this is the notation that was used in the course

Comment: The fractional part of a number is what is left after you subtract the largest integer that is no larger, so the fractional part of $2.345$ is $0.345$.  It is often denoted by braces.  I would write your sequence as $a_n=\frac 5n$ with no punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the sequence is monotonically decreasing.

It is convergent, as you say.

An upper bound is just a number that is at least as large as all the members of the sequence, and a lower bound is just a number at least as small as all the members of the sequence.  $1000$ is an upper bound and $-1000$ is a lower bound, so the sequence is bounded.  There are tighter bounds, $5$ and $0$, but we were not asked for the greatest lower bound and least upper bound.

Comment: I think the OP's notation was misleading. The OP probably meant to say $a_n = \frac{5}{n}$ and the curly brackets were notation for sequence not the fractional part. I fixed it above.

Comment: @ZeroXLR Your assumption was correct, thanks for the edit

Comment: @ZeroXLR:  I would just have asked OP in a comment.  Using braces to represent a sequence is not standard, as a set normally has no order.

Comment: @RossMillikan Well to be completely exact the OP's braces also had the usual subscript and superscript for sequences i.e. it was of the form $\{-\}_{n = 1}^\infty$

Answer (score 1):

It's bounded by 0 below and 5 above.

Comment: Could you explain your line of reasoning?

Comment: for all $n\in N$, we have $0 <  \frac{5}{n} \leq 5$

Answer (score 1):

The sequence is monotonically decreasing, converges to $0$, and is bounded above by $5$ and below by $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your 3rd claim is wrong as all above have suggested. Also, the reasoning would follow this order:

- the sequence is *monotonically decreasing*
- the sequence is *bounded above* by $5$ *and below* by $0$
- hence by *monotone-bounded theorem*,the sequence converges to a real number,in this case to *$0$*.